# how to get data from label or span and transfer it to a div, an other span or a label

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

this is my form with div :

```
<form action="" method="post">


                 <label name="meal" value="meal">
                    Soupe 
                 </label>

                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span id="prix" name="price" >price</span></td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="nbr" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"value="1">        
                            <label>Number of persons</label>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="button" id="somebutton" value="order"   
                                onclick="getdata('somebutton','empty-basket-wrapper')" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">description of the meal ....</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
</form>

   <div class="order">
                <div class="panier">
                    <span class="Ib"></span>
                    <span class="oh">my shopping cart</span>
                </div>
                <div id="empty-basket-wrapper">
                empty
                </div>
    </div>
```

I would like when I click on the button, the datas to be transferred from the the label or span like soupe and price and be displayed in the div id ="empty-basket-wrapper".

I guess my problem is how to get data from label or span and transfer it to div or an other span or label

this is my AJAX :

```
var _xhr;
var _target;
function getdata(sourceId,targetId){

    _xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

    _xhr.onreadystatechange=callback;
    _xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    _xhr.send();

    var px=document.getElementById("prix").name;


    function callback() {

        _target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        _target.innerHTML=px//_xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: 'Possible' duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327457/how-to-get-data-from-label-or-span-and-transfer-it-to-div-or-an-other-span-or-la

Comment: yes it is , it mine too I will delete it. I am looking a solution as soon I can possible

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using jQuery, then it would be like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#somebutton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(e.target).closest("form");
        var target = $(form).attr("action");
        $.post(target, form.serialize(), function(result) {
            // your POST Target could give you HTML for the cart contents
            $("#empty-basket-wrapper").html(result);
            // your AJAX endpoint could also give you a JSON, then you could use mustache to render.
        });
    });

});
```

If you just want to popup the values in the cart and not POST back to your server you don't need no AJAX ... not sure if you mean that. If so, it would be simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#somebutton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(e.target).closest("form");
        // for sure you should investigate something more sophisticated, see mustache
        $("#empty-basket-wrapper").html(form.serialize());
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answer 
I need AJAX obligatory in my application please can you suggest me any solution with AJAX ?

Comment: If AJAX is obligatory (which it shouldn't be unless it is a exercise :-) take the first solution and write a PHP Script (or any server-side, stateful programming language) to interpret the form and have it output a html formatted representation of the cart content. Make that the form action and it should insert the state of the cart into your div.

Comment: yeh Thanks I'm not using php, I'm using jee, just if can transform your jQuery code to AJAX please